# SQL select all ids with the max value, then count how many rows are associated with each id

Tags: sql, db2

Suppose I have the following table **HASCO**:

```
Table HASCO

+--------+------+-----+
|PID     |Amount|Date |
+--------+------+-----+
|1       |1000  |Date1|
+--------+------+-----+
|1       |8000  |Date2|
+--------+------+-----+
|2       |8000  |Date3|
+--------+------+-----+
|2       |3000  |Date4|
+--------+------+-----+
|2       |4000  |Date5|
+--------+------+-----+
|3       |4000  |Date6|
+--------+------+-----+
```

I wanna get the following result:

```
+--------+--------+
|PID     |numTours|
+--------+--------+
|1       |2       |
+--------+--------+
|2       |3       |
+--------+--------+
```

PID 1 and 2 both have the maximum amount 8000, then PID 1 has 2 rows and PID 2 has three rows.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT HASCO.PID, COUNT(*) AS numTour
FROM HASCO
GROUP BY HASCO.PID
HAVING HASCO.PID IN
(
SELECT HASCO.PID
FROM HASCO
WHERE HASCO.AMOUNT = (SELECT MAX(HASCO.AMOUNT) FROM HASCO)
```

**This works on db2 but is there a better way to do it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sub-query in `Having` clause can simplified to

```
SELECT HASCO.PID, COUNT(*) AS numTour
FROM HASCO
GROUP BY HASCO.PID
HAVING max(HASCO.AMOUNT) = (SELECT MAX(HASCO.AMOUNT) FROM HASCO)
```

If `DB2` supports windowed aggregate functions then

```
Select PID,count(1)
(
Select HASCO.PID,
       Max(AMOUNT)Over() as Max_amount,
       Max(AMOUNT) Over(Partition by PID) as Max_Pid_Amt
From HASCO
) A
Where Max_amount = Max_Pid_Amt
Group by PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
WITH MAXIVALUE(SELECT MAX(HASCO.AMOUNT) maxi FROM HASCO)
SELECT f1.PID, COUNT(*) AS numTours
FROM HASCO f1
GROUP BY f1.PID
HAVING max(f1.AMOUNT) = (SELECT maxi  FROM MAXIVALUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2

```
with hasmaxi (
select distinct f1.pid from HASCO f1
where exists 
(select 1 from HASCO f2 having max(f2.AMOUNT)=f1.AMOUNT)
)
SELECT f3.PID, COUNT(*) AS numTours
FROM HASCO f3 inner join hasmaxi f4 on f3.PID=f4.f1.PID
GROUP BY f3.PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 3

```
SELECT f3.PID, COUNT(*) AS numTours
FROM HASCO f3 inner join 
               (
                 select distinct f1.pid from HASCO f1
                 where exists 
                 (select 1 from HASCO f2 having max(f2.AMOUNT)=f1.AMOUNT)
               ) f4 on f3.PID=f4.f1.PID
GROUP BY f3.PID
```